# NullReference Exception was unhandles

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm having trouble when adding new team to the dataTable. VisualStudio is pointing at line teams.Rows.Add(dr) with NullReference error. Can you please help me?

```
        private void addTeam(String nazwa)
    {

        DataRow dr = players.NewRow();
        //dr["playerID"] = nazwa;

        dr["nazwa"] = nazwa;
        teams.Rows.Add(dr); //<--there is en error
    }


class Program
{
    static DataTable players ;
    static DataTable teams;
    private DataSet teamMenager;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the variable "teams"? `teams = new Datatable();` along with all of the column definitions etc.

Comment: You should create the row with the same table you'll add it back to later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

The `DataTable` is not yet [initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
static DataTable teams;
```

You can initilaize it for example with the [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
static DataTable teams = new DataTable();
static DataTable players = new DataTable();
```

Although it's not clear why you made them static. This would mean that every instance of `Program` would share the same `DataTable` which can be problematic with multiple threads since you need to provide a locking mechanism. Just remove the static and create an instance of `Program`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Program p = new Program();
    p.Start(); // open your form(s) there and add teams or what else
    // ...
```

**Edit**: There's something else wrong. You're creating the new `DataRow` via `players.NewRow` but adding it to the DataTable `teams`. That is not allowed. Every DataRow belongs to one DataTable. That cannot be changed and will result in an `ArgumentException`.

```
DataRow dr = players.NewRow();
dr["nazwa"] = nazwa;
```

so add it to players instead:

```
players.Rows.Add(dr); //<--there is en error
```

Comment: I'm initializing player DataTable in main. Also it's filled with  some data which i can read. Problem is only with inserting function.

Comment: @user1877249: Not sure why you're getting a NullReferenceException then. But you're adding the DataRow to the wrong DataTable. You either have to use teams.NewRow or players.Rows.Add.

Comment: Yep. I corrected that but still getting error. Also changed Main to public but no effect.

Comment: @user1877249: You are using `teams` and `players` DataTables in `addTeam`. But that is not in the class `Program` and you're not referencing the DataTables from `Program`, do you? What DataTables are you referencing? You haven't shown us them, but they are not initialized.

Comment: I think i got it. I redeclarred datatable teams with all columns in addTeam function and it's not crashing. Can you tell me how to make visible columns from main to all other functions?

Comment: @user1877249: Either leave them `public static` and reference them via `Program.teams` or `Program.players` or pass references of `Program` to the methods where you need it.